# apache proxy, protect folder, exclude file

Tags: reverse-proxy, apache2

I'm using apache as a reverse proxy and I was wondering how can I protect a folder but exclude a file within that folder.
For example if I use

```
<Proxy http://192.168.1.10/myfolder>
  Require ip x.x.x.x
</Proxy>
```

how can I proxy to 192.168.1.10/myfolder/myfile.php?

Answer (score 0):

I added the following above the folder configuration and it worked.

```
<Proxy http://192.168.1.10/myfolder/myfile.php>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  Satisfy Any
</Proxy>
```